# How to fetch TOraQuery in a separate thread?

Tags: delphi, odac

I have a `TOraQuery`, that query I use with option `FetchAll`. And it loads about 55000 rows. And this fetching takes a long time. I want to bring this fetching in a separate thread. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want only that one Fetch in a separate thread or do you want the whole query in separated threads?

Comment: @fisi-pjm I think just one Fetch

Answer (score 1):

Searching the property list ([ODAC TOraQuery Properties](https://www.devart.com/odac/docs/devart.odac.toraquery%20properties.htm)) for thread gives:

> **NonBlocking** (inherited from TOraDataSet)
>
> Used to execute a SQL statement and fetch rows by a separate thread.

The help for TOraDataset.NonBlocking has in the remarks section:

> Set the NonBlocking property to True to execute SQL statement and
> fetch rows by a separate thread.

Comment: What about settings for session?

Comment: The session defaults to ThreadSafety = true which is what is needed to use NonBlocking with a TOraQuery or TOraDataset.